# Solr delete document by stored value

Tags: solr, lucene

I have the following schema.

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" stored="true"/>
    <field name="general" type="text" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="title" type="string" stored="true"/>
    <field name="description" type="string" stored="true"/>
    <field name="entity_type" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="entity_id" type="int" stored="true"/>
    <field name="pic" type="string" stored="true"/>
</fields>
```

I want to delete documents by stored value for example by id field. Is that possible?

If it is not possible what I should delete to achieve that? If I'll need to make id field indexed, how can I convert them to indexed without reimporting data?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to define field id as your [uniqueKey](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey). Than you can just delete the docs by using this id. See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey#Use_cases_which_require_a_unique_key)

Answer (score 1):

The Id field needs to be indexed if you intend to use it in query.
If you mark the field as indexed, would need full re-importing of the data as the analysis as already being performed

Comment: No way to force Lucene to regenerate index himself?

Comment: no Lucene/solr will not do anything by itself. As it is an change in schema structure, the documents would need to be reindexed.